# How can i fix this kind of mesh problem?

Tags: mesh, topology, retopology

I am attempting to model a car.

While filling in the vertices, I noticed a shading issue in the mesh.

[image]
Bad topology.

I attempted to resolve the problem by deleting vertices and remeshing it myself, but the issue persists. I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/